# Populate an int64 DataFrame column based on index of a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with all int64-type columns.

```
  City  Val  ...
0    3    1  
1    2   43  
2    0   32  
3    1   54
```

Then, I have a list of category names:

```
names = ['Sydney', 'Tokyo', 'Vancouver', 'Toronto']
```

What I want to do is , based on the `names` list index i.e., 0 = 'Sydney' and 1 = 'Tokyo', populate the City column with city names.

Desirable result:

```
       City Val  ...
0   Toronto   1  
1 Vancouver  43  
2    Sydney  32  
3     Tokyo  54
```

I tried: `df['City'].loc[df['City'].isin(names), df['City']]=names.index(df['City'])`, but get an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

AND, I'd like to change the City column into a category type.

```
    df['City'] = df['City'].astype('category')
    df['City'].cat.set_categories(names, ordered=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created by `enumerate`:

```
names = ['Sydney', 'Tokyo', 'Vancouver', 'Toronto']
df['City'] = df['City'].map(dict(enumerate(names)))
print (df)
        City  Val
0    Toronto    1
1  Vancouver   43
2     Sydney   32
3      Tokyo   54
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dict(enumerate(names)))
{0: 'Sydney', 1: 'Tokyo', 2: 'Vancouver', 3: 'Toronto'}
```

Then for categoricals:

```
df['City'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['City'].map(dict(enumerate(names))),
                                 ordered=True, 
                                 categories=names)
```

Or:

```
df['City'] = (df['City'].map(dict(enumerate(names)))
                       .astype('category', ordered=True, categories=names))
```

Comment: You are a legend, mate! Thanks a ton.